# Failed to compile SLS file

Tags: salt-stack

I have a sls file in the path /srv/salt/server3.sls.
 Its content is

```
git:
pkg:
- installed
```

When I run the SLS as

```
sudo salt 'ubuntu' state.sls server3
```

It gives the following error

```
ubuntu:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    ID git in SLS server3 is not a dictionary
----------
    ID pkg in SLS server3 is not a dictionary
```

What wrong am I doing here? please help me with this

Answer (score 4):

yaml cares about indentation. this is a yaml error

```
git:
pkg:
- installed
```

you want to indent pkg two spaces under git

```
git:
  pkg:
    - installed
```

If you run a state through yaml lint before saving it, you'll see the errors.

Here is the result of your state:

```
--- 
git: ~
pkg: 
  - installed
```

notice that `git` is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today (thats how I found this). At the end it was an identation error. Mixed tabs and spaces.

In your case try:

```
git:
  pkg.installed
```